# Retrofit и SharedPreferences: Как сохранить полученный токен?

Tags: java, android

Не получается сохранить токен. В файле preferences.xml сохраняется такая строка:
com.example.myapp.data.network.RequestBody@a7a3bc8, хотя я должен получить хэш из 32 символов.
Помогите разобраться! Ниже мой код...

```
public class SharedPreferencesUtils {

    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "preferences";

    static Context CONTEXT;

    public SharedPreferencesUtils(Context context) {
        CONTEXT = context;
    }

    public void saveToken(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                CONTEXT.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String loadToken(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                CONTEXT.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, value);
    }
}


private void sendRequestRegisterToken() {
        ResponseBody hexPost = new ResponseBody();
        hexPost.token = mToken;
        Call<RequestBody> call = mService.postToken(hexPost);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RequestBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<RequestBody> call, @NonNull Response<RequestBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    SharedPreferencesUtils shared = new SharedPreferencesUtils(getApplicationContext());
                    shared.saveToken(SharedPreferencesUtils.APP_PREFERENCES, response.body().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<RequestBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

---

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(" ")
Call<List<RequestBody>> postParams(@Field("id_token") String id_token);
```

Comment: может поле в классе другого типа отличного от строкового?

Comment: 1) Вы не перепутали классы местами? `ResponseBody` (в переводе на русский) - тело **ответа**. 2) переопределите метод `toString()` у класса ответа так чтобы он возвращал нужное значение, либо вместо него используйте поле или геттер нужного значения

Comment: Получилось переопределить метод toString на метод получения токена, спасибо...